# Remove main site link from user dashboard in multisite of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have created a multi site website in wordpress, I want to remove main site link from user admin area, Please prefer screenshot.[image]

Please guide me how can i remove it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install & network activate User Role Editor plugin from http://example.com/wp-admin/network/plugins.php
2. Then go to Settings > User Role Editor menu on network and make sure you have the settings as shown in following screenshot.

[Check image this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyhww.png)

3. Go to "User Role Editor" settings page on your main site http://example.com/wp-admin/users.php?page=users-user-role-editor.php and select the "Administrator" role. Then remove the capabilities which you want to remove. For example, in below screenshot you can see that all User related capabilities have been removed. Do note that I have checked "Apply to All Sites" so that it applies to all the sites on the network.

[Check image this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFlP7.png)

4. Now check backend of any of your subsite and you will notice that "Users" menu is no more there. Similarly you can hide other menu pages as intended. Let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: Yes, I had do as per your instruction, but this is for user capability, I am not getting my solution by this plugin.

Comment: can you come on anydesk